# Compare previous request value with the current value php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Well i have a page, which gets refreshed EVERY second. For every request, a random value will be generated and will be sent to the server.

```
$random_number = $_REQUEST['rand'];
```

This is my scenario - For every second, i will have a random value. I need to pull greater value by comparing with the previous value(from previous request)

```
time(seconds)   random values   considered value  
    1                 5               5    // 5 > null or 0. so it is 5
    2                 1               5    // 1 < 5. so it is 5
    3                 6               6    // 6 > 1. so it is 6
    4                 4               6    // 4 < 6. so it is 6
    5                 2               4    // 2 < 4. so it is 4
    6                 4               4    // 4 > 2. so it is 8
```

And for every request, i need to run UPDATE query, for whichever my considered values are greater than previous values.

EDIT - How do i run UPDATE query based on the greater value considered every time?

Comment: what is the question than???

Comment: Well, you'd need to store the previous value somewhere, possible with SESSION or perhaps a cookie, and then simply do the compare as you demonstrated?

Comment: Cool. I can't see any problems here. Is it task?

Comment: Store value in Session

Comment: Thanks for the suggessions.. I have updated my question.. Facing problem in storing previous values in sessions. and comparing with the current value

Comment: What has this got to do with SQL?

Comment: @strawberry, Priorities of running my query. My considered value in my table shows..

Comment: I have no idea what that means.

Comment: for time = 2seconds, even though my random value is 1, i would consider my previous value. since it greater.

firstime - update tablename where value = 5(prev value is 0)
second time - update table where value = 5(prev value is 5 > 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do below changes in your php file

```
$random_number = $_REQUEST['rand'];
if(isset($_SESSION['random_number']) && $_SESSION['random_number']>0) // check wether last random number is available in session, (i.e for first run there will be no previous random number)
{
     $old_random_number = $_SESSION['random_number'];
     // do your comparison and mysql update queries here
}
$_SESSION['random_number'] = $random_number; // update the session variable with new random number
```

dont forget to put `session_start()` on the top of your PHP page..

let me know if any help needed.

Comment: Thanks nishant. Will try this.. and i'l come back